# Packaged application for CRUD operations on a database

Tags: database, docker, crud, open-source

I know that there are many tools for the visualization of databases such as metabase, grafana, tableau, superset ...

But I don't know of any packaged software that allows CRUD operations (crete, read, update and delete) on a database.

This problem has been presented to me several times in several of my projects, wanting to make a table available to a user and that does not merit custom development. I bet a lot of people must have this same situation

But I have not found any packaged software that provides crud operations on a database table. So it seems extremely strange to me and I wanted to see why, is there a design problem in this functionality? Or am I just doing the wrong google search and these softwares have another name?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like a Database Management Tool?

You have plenty of them, personally I use [DBeaver](https://dbeaver.io/).

If you mean about frameworks which generate a boilerplate API with CRUD operations, you have [Loopback](https://loopback.io/), from IBM.

And if you mean something you could access as a web-application, then you have [PHPMyAdmin](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/) if you're focused into MySQL/MariaDB.

Comment: yes, but but something stupidly simple, that I can integrate with an LDAP, I use DBeaver, but I am not going to ask a user to use it. Loopback and PHPMyAdmin I never used them, I will investigate them, thank you very much

Comment: You have also pgAdmin (https://www.pgadmin.org/) if you are using PostgreSQL. Those tools are authenticated against the database credentials, so if you want to actually implement LDAP authentication you should sync your AD with the database users. Loopback is a framework so you can generate an API, so probably not what you're looking for.

Comment: Try a sandbox of pgAdmin to check if it's what you want here: https://www.katacoda.com/enterprisedb/scenarios/pgadmin-sandbox

Comment: in the case of loopback, it seems oriented to offer services, not a web interface. PHPMyAdmin seems to be mysql only and is more like a database client for programmers, not a simple CRUD to give access to a user who does not know SQL.

Comment: Thank you very much again, but regarding pgadmin I see it as a tool that guides programmers, not end users

Comment: If you want something really simple and in the "clicky" style to access and modify data in a form-based way, you have also DTM Data Editor. But any of the previous tools have also a view where they can check, edit and filter data without SQL knowledge.